# Swift array - if a value does not exist

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a UIPickerView that loads data to an array - it's working, but
then I have the same UIPickerView on another page that I want to display data that is saved when I select an item. This works, if the data exists in the array. If the data dose not exist an index out of range error occurs, and the app crashes.

```
    if data[indexRow].isEmpty
    {
        distanceLabel.text = ""//works
    }else if (){//need this code
        print("data")
    }else print("data")//need this code
```

What I need is, how can I test if the value dose not exists (has not been entered on the previous page) in the array without crashing the app.

Comment: `if indexRow < data.count { // do something element exists at index`

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the `index` is greater than or equal to the number of items in your data array.

```
if(index < data.count){
    // When data exists
} else{
    // When data does not exist
}
```

Comment: Thanks but no still getting an Index out of range error

Comment: Yes sorry that is the solution. Thanks

Comment: Remember to accept this as the answer if it answered your question.